# Excel - linked cells

Tags: excel, linked-list

I have one table in Sheet1 with next data

[image]

and second table in Sheet2 with simular data

[image]

As you can see in first table in first row i have

```
Item No     Loc     Type    Quantity
231          A        1       34
```

and in second table

```
Item No     Loc     Type    Quantity
 231         A       1       11
 231         A       1       12
 231         A       1       11
```

Quantity in first table is sum of quantity in second table group by 
item No, Loc, Type.

How i can link quantity from first table when press 34 to open second table with data how i got this 34?

Any idea???

Comment: So when you click on cell 34, you would like the sheet to jump to table 2 and show you all items that make up the 34?

Comment: I can't think of any native way so probably have to use a VBA macro to achieve this.

Comment: ok, can you give me example using VBA macro

Comment: Sure, look up `Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` as a method to run a macro when you click on 34.

Comment: i am new in excel can you give me all example please

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a free code writing service. I would suggest to learn the basics of VBA, record a few macros and see what you have there, and THEN when you run into problems post a new question with your code and we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Pivot Table with row field Layout and Print settings set to "Show item labels in tabular form".
[image: Pivot table Layout & Print]

This will give you a table like this:

[image: Pivot tabular layout]

When you double-click the "34" a new sheet will be added showing the source data rows used to calculate the total quantity:

[image: Pivot double-click]

Answer (score -1):

[image: sumifs]

Use =sumifs() function.

see image for more details

Comment: But i want when press 34 to select in Sheet2 in table row that used to get this 34

Comment: can i use vb script